# Complementary Pwm in STM32F103C6T6A

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaNPR.jpg)In complementary PWM out put my dead time increases or decreases when i am varying the Auto reload register value. is there a solution like 45% of duty cycle with one out put inverted and second output non inverted.

This is my HAL_INITS.

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_DOWN;
  htim1.Init.Period = 400;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 110;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}
```

Timer Hal Start.

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
 
HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
```

Method to change the frequency and duty.

```
void pwmData(uint32_t dat){
    
    __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim1,dat);
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1,dat/2);
}
```

The change in frequency is Adc dependent.

for your reference i have attached few images.

thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72X4j.jpg)